# Create RSpec context inside a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In order to avoid repeating myself a lot in my Rspec tests, I'd like to write a function like this

```
def with_each_partner(&block)
  PARTNER_LIST.each do |partner|
    context "with partner #{partner.name}" { yield partner }
  end
end
```

I have such a function and it works in the sense that all the tests run with the correct value for partner supplied, but they don't print during output as being part of the "with partner X" context: instead if I have a test like this:

```
describe Thing do
  subject { Thing.new(partner) }
  with_each_partner do |partner|
    it 'does its thing' do
      expect(subject.do).to eq 'its thing'
    end
  end
end
```

I end up with output like this:

```
Thing
  does its thing
```

Instead of the desired output, which is like:

```
Thing
  with partner X
    does its thing
  with partner Y
    does its thing
```

How can I get RSpec to correctly work with the context created in my function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: do this:

```
def with_each_partner(&block)
  PARTNER_LIST.each do |partner|
    context "with partner #{partner.name}" do
      class_exec(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

#### Explanation

RSpec's DSL works by evaluating the blocks with a changed `self` -- this is how `it` is a method within a `describe` or `context` block, but not outside of it.  When you `yield`, the provided block is evaluated with the original `self` that was `self` at the point the block was defined.  What that means is that with your original `with_each_partner` definition, this code:

```
describe Thing do
  subject { Thing.new(partner) }
  with_each_partner do |partner|
    it 'does its thing' do
      expect(subject.do).to eq 'its thing'
    end
  end
end
```

Is really being evaluated like this:

```
describe Thing do
  subject { Thing.new(partner) }
  outer_example_group = self
  with_each_partner do |partner|
    outer_example_group.it 'does its thing' do
      expect(subject.do).to eq 'its thing'
    end
  end
end
```

...and so the individual examples are defined on the outer example group, not on the `"with partner #{partner.name}"` nested group.

`class_exec` [evaluates the provided block in the context of the class/module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-class_exec). In this case, the class is the example group subclass that RSpec has generated for your context. Using `class_exec` ensures that when `it` is called, the receiver is your nested `context` example group rather than the outer example group, creating the result you want.

Comment: dang, i think this is just about the best answer i ever got on SO. +1

Comment: Heh.  Well...I do believe this gentleman has some familiarity with [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec).

Comment: Hi there! I have a question about your answer. When you do class_exec(&block), how are you passing the partner into that block so that it's accessible in the block?

Comment: Try with `class_exec(partner, &block)`